# What is Scala way of finding whether all the elements of an Array has same length?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am new to Scala and but very old to Java and had some understanding working with FP languages like "Haskell".

Here I am wondering how to implement this using Scala. There is a list of elements in an array all of them are strings and I just want to know if there is a way I can do this in Scala in a FP way. Here is my current version which works...

```
def checkLength(vals: Array[String]): Boolean = {
  var len = -1
  for(x <- conts){
    if(len < 0)
      len = x.length()
    else{
      if (x.length() != len)
        return false
      else
        len = x.length()
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

And I am pretty sure there is a better way of doing this in Scala/FP...

Comment: It's reasonably atypical that your 13 lines of Java (it's basically Java you've written, in Scala syntax) can be reduced to 1 line of scala. The 1 scala line being infinitely more readable, understandable and hence maintainable! I say **atypical**, normally you could only condense 13 lines of Java into 2 of scala!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
list.forall( str => str.size == list(0).size )
```

Edit: Here's a definition that's as general as possilbe and also allows to check whether a property other than length is the same for all elements:

```
def allElementsTheSame[T,U](f: T => U)(list: Seq[T]) = {
    val first: Option[U] = list.headOption.map( f(_) )
    list.forall( f(_) == first.get ) //safe to use get here!
}

type HasSize = { val size: Int }
val checkLength = allElementsTheSame((x: HasSize) => x.size)_

checkLength(Array( "123", "456") )

checkLength(List( List(1,2), List(3,4) ))
```

Comment: +1 Yep. Couldn't the lattern term even just be `list forall (_.size == list(0).size)` ?

Comment: Excellent. After some trails, I ended up doing this... 

`def checkLenght(vals: Array[String]): Boolean = vals.forall(_.length == vals(0).length)`

Comment: @Teja Kantamneni: Note that if you leave out the check for the size, you'll get an error when applying the method to empty arrays. Also note that if you declare vals as `Seq[String]` instead of `Array[String]`, it will also work for Lists etc., not just Arrays. (You could also generalize it to work on sequences of anything that has a length method, instead of just strings).

Comment: @sepp2k: Well, It should not throw any error as you will go into the loop only if there is an element. Actually I am really new to Scala world and I just started learning it last weekend. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Your `list.size == 0 ||` is redundant so I've removed it

Comment: But your generalization in the `allElementsTheSame` method would of course fail for an empty list. You probably want to use `headOption`

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: Is `headOption` equal to Haskell `head`??

Comment: No - `headOption` returns `None` on an empty sequence or `Some(head)` in the case of a non-empty list. It's fixed now

Comment: oxbow_lakes: Good points. I was stupid about the size check. Especially in the general method where I checked the size *after* accessing the first element.

Comment: On of the things you'll find about Scala is that the language is so concise, adding such "helper" methods is usually unnecessary - it doesn't add anything to the conciseness or readability of the resultant code. In Java-land, you end up writing so much extraneous stuff! Scala tool support may not quite be up to the level of Java's but this doesn't make you any less productive!

Comment: I see I'll have to be way more active on Stack Overflow if I'm ever to have fun writing Scala answers again... :-)

Comment: It may be safe to `use get here` but it does seem a shame to evaluate it each loop...

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, i'm not sure I agree about helper functions being unnecessary. It's immediately obvious (from the name) what the helper function is doing. It isn't as quick to work out how the code does it, at least for mere mortals like me. There's a "think, think, ah, so that's what it's checking" process - and with a less trivial case, that adds up to a lot of unnecessary thinking time. I think some of Kent Beck's smalltalk patterns like "decomposing message" and "intention revealing method" are just as applicable when translated to Scala...

Answer (score 7):

Since everyone seems to be so creative, I'll be creative too. :-)

```
def checkLength(vals: Array[String]): Boolean = vals.map(_.length).removeDuplicates.size <= 1
```

Mind you, `removeDuplicates` will likely be named `distinct` on Scala 2.8.

Comment: Clever!  But until it's renamed, `(Set() ++ list.map(_.length)).size <= 1` is even shorter.

Answer (score 3):

Tip: Use `forall` to determine whether all elements in the collection do satisfy a certain predicate (e.g. equality of length).

Answer (score 2):

If you know that your lists are always non-empty, a straight forall works well.  If you don't, it's easy to add that in:

```
list match {
  case x :: rest => rest forall (_.size == x.size)
  case _ => true
}
```

Now lists of length zero return true instead of throwing exceptions.

Comment: Is pattern matching possible on arrays?

Comment: @Dario - yes, they match against sequences. This behaviour has changed slightly in 2.8 but they can still be used in pattern-matching

Comment: @Dario - Yes.  If "list" is an array, use `case Array(x,rest @ _*) =>` instead.  This works in both 2.7 and 2.8.

Answer (score 2):

```
list.groupBy{_.length}.size == 1
```

You convert the list into a map of groups of equal length strings. If all the strings have the same length, then the map will hold only one such group.

The nice thing with this solution is that you don't need to know anything about the length of the strings, and don't need to comapre them to, say, the first string. It works well on an empty string, in which case it returns false (if that's what you want..)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another approach:

```
def check(list:List[String]) = list.foldLeft(true)(_ && list.head.length == _.length)
```

Comment: `forall` approach is more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just my €0.02

```
def allElementsEval[T, U](f: T => U)(xs: Iterable[T]) =
  if (xs.isEmpty) true
  else {
    val first = f(xs.head)
    xs forall { f(_) == first }
  }
```

This works with any `Iterable`, evaluates f the minimum number of times possible, and while the block can't be curried, the type inferencer can infer the block parameter type.

```
  "allElementsEval" should "return true for an empty Iterable" in {
    allElementsEval(List[String]()){ x => x.size } should be (true)
  }
  it should "eval the function at each item" in {
    allElementsEval(List("aa", "bb", "cc")) { x => x.size } should be (true)
    allElementsEval(List("aa", "bb", "ccc")) { x => x.size } should be (false)
  }
  it should "work on Vector and Array as well" in {
    allElementsEval(Vector("aa", "bb", "cc")) { x => x.size } should be (true)
    allElementsEval(Vector("aa", "bb", "ccc")) { x => x.size } should be (false)
    allElementsEval(Array("aa", "bb", "cc")) { x => x.size } should be (true)
    allElementsEval(Array("aa", "bb", "ccc")) { x => x.size } should be (false)
  }
```

It's just a shame that `head :: tail` pattern matching fails so insidiously for Iterables.